# DB generated list not working when created using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, xajax

I have a simple form that has a list (dropdown list generated from a DB), when a user makes a selection, the selection is printed on the screen. The problem I'm having is that if I use jquery to call the php funciton that generates the list when the page is loading, the list will not work, but if I add the code directly in the html it will work 
 
When the page loads the dropdown list is called like this:

```
$('#createDropDown').ready(function(){
        id = $('#createDropDown').val(); 
        // this calls a php function that creates a dropdown list from the DB
        // the dropdown's id = 'categoryList'
        xajax_addDropdownMenu(id);
```

});

the list is generated with the **id = 'categoryList'**, and it is appended correctly to the createDropDown DIV called "createDropDown". Up until now everything looks good!
The problem comes when a selection is made on the newly created list (categoryList) another Jquery is called

when a selection is made the following code should be called:

```
$('#categoryList').change(function() {
    bucket_id = $('#categoryList').val(); 
    var selected = "";
    // get selected value from the dropdown menu
        $("#categoryList option:selected").each(function () {
            selected += $(this).text() + " ===>";
         });
        // if we have a valid ID print it in the screen.
        if(bucket_id!= 0)
        {
            xajax_addCategory(selected);
        }
     });
```

**xajax_addCategory(selected);** prints the selected item on the screen. but is not working.

NOTE: This works OK if I call the php function to generate the dropdown directly in the main.html file, so I know that the list is being generated with the correct ID and it works, but when I use Jquery to call the php method on load, it doesn't work... and I don't understand why.

PS I'm a noob of Jquery so some insight would be very welcome!

---

UPDATE:

I tried creating a binding after the list is generated like this:

```
 
$('#createDropDown').ready(function()
    { 
        id = $('#createDropDown').val();  
        xajax_addDropdownMenu(id); 
        $("#categoryList0").bind('change',function() 
        { 
            console.log('The code goes here!!'); 
        }); 
    });
```

where **categoryList0 is the ID** of the new list. the class of the list is categoryList

but I'm still stuck because it is still not getting into the function when there is a change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second code snippet finds all elements that match #categoryList and binds a function to the change event. The problem is that there is no #categoryList element at that time, since you create it later on. Thus you need to do the binding after the list has been created.

Comment: and how do I do that?
how can I create the binding after the list is created?

Comment: You need to hook into xajax and have it run the code in your second snippet when it has added the list. Since I don't know xajax I cannot tell you how.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do a binding later using xajax. For some reason nowhere in the jquery file I was able to bind this function with the new drop down. My solution was to add the jquery scrip using xajaxResopnse->addScript(script) in the **addDropdownMenu** funciton like this

function addDropdownMenu($id){

```
  $xajaxResponse = new xajaxResponse();

  $html = /* CODE TO GENERATE LIST HERE */ ; 


  $javascript = /*"*///commented out " to visualize code better
    $('#categoryList').bind('change',function categoryListChange() 
    {
     
      //get selected value from the dropdown menu
      var selected = "";
      $("#categoryList option:selected").each(function () 
      {
        selected += $(this).text();
       });

      bucketId = $('#categoryList').val(); 

      if(bucketId!= 0)
      {
        xajax_addCategory(selected);
      }

    });"";

  $xajaxResponse->addAppend("categoryListContainer", "innerHTML", $html);

  $xajaxResponse->addScript($javascript);

  return $xajaxResponse;  

}
```

first doing a bind for the new list like this **$('#categoryList').bind('change',function categoryListChange() {...}** 
and then 
 adding the jquery script through **$xajaxResponse->addScript($javascript);**.